# Extend GPT System Partition

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have a Tablet notebook having **C: drive** (system drive) as **GPT**, while other drives are **MBR** (this information is shown in partition tool). I have been trying to extend system drive using windows Disk management tool, [EasyUS](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/resize-gpt-disk-partition.html) and [AOMEI](https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/extend-volume-greyed-out-windows-10-0528.html). But I am unable to get any option to extend so far.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to **extend** system partition present in **GPT Disk1** from unallocated space in **MBR disk2**? Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "extend" a partition on one disk into another disk. Partitions must be contained within a single drive.*

*Unless you are using an advanced disk partition, access method or format such as [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID), [Windows Dynamic Discs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx), or some other method that merges disks.

These are not easy to set up on "live" disks and can be potentially harmful to your data.

Comment: So that means I should give up probably :p